# Thread-level parallelism for set of mutually exclusive tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing

I've encountered a problem while processing streaming data with C++. Data comes in entries, size of each entry is comparatively small, and the task processing each entry does not take much time. But each entry, as well as the task processing that entry, is assigned to a *class* (a concept, not C++ class), where only one of the tasks belonging to a same class can be executed at a time.

Besides, there are billions of entries and ten millions of classes, and entry comes in random classes.

I found it difficult to parallelize these tasks. Any suggestion of how to speed up the process will be great help!

Really thanks!

Comment: This is a very messy requirement.  Can you give any more details?  Maybe we can think of some workaround. An array of tens of millions of semaphores does not sound promising:(

Comment: Try having a pool of queues, each queue is either inactive or holds items of one class, each queue is served by its own thread.

Comment: Each entry is a row of SQL table, which is guaranteed to have a column denote a user. Therefore 'class' here is actually a user id.

Answer (score 0):

Put the work entries into a set of class-specific work queues.  Use the queue size as as a priority with larger size having priority over smaller sizes.  Set up a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) (of queues) to hold the class specific work queues based on their size as priority.

Work entries are entered into their corresponding queue if nobody is processing that queue.

Set up a thread pool of about the same size as the number of CPUs you have.

Each thread asks the priority queue for the highest priority work queue, which is the one that arguably holds the most work.  The thread removes the class queue from the priority queue.   It then processes all the elements in that queue, without locking it; this keeps the overhead per unit small.

If new members of that class show up in the meantime, they are added to a new queue for that class but not placed in the priority queue. The worker thread on using up current queue, checks for a new queue of the same class and processes that if present.

Comment: Tens of millions of queues?

Comment: OP has tens of millions of objects.  Why should tens of millions of queues bother him?  Actually, he  only needs queues for classes for which there are unprocessed members if done right.  You might need an array containing null or a pointer to a queue with one slot per class.  That's 40Mb.  Pfft.

Answer (score 0):

You will want one task processor per hardware processor or so, assuming CPU is at least somewhat involved.

Each processor locks a set of active classes, slurps a bunch of jobs off the front of the queue that can be run given the current set state, marks those as in use in the set, unlocks the set and queue, and processes.

How many jobs per slurp varies with the rate of jobs, the number of processors, and how clumped and latency sensitive they are.

Starvation should be impossible, as the unslurped elements should be high proirity once the class is free to be processed.

Work in batches to keep the contention for set and queue low: ideally dynamically change the batch size based off contention, idle, and latency information.

This makes the overhead stay proportional to number of processors, not number of task-classes.

Comment: I've tried similar approaches, but it turn out that, each processor must have a queue of tasks, and lock when push and pop from queue is inevitable. To alleviate this, I managed to use a queue that locks less than naive implementation. I've posted it at https://gist.github.com/zxytim/8611754. But although I've done such optimization, despite the number of processors using, it is still slower than sequential one.

Comment: @Tim I don't see why a given processor thread's internal queue need involve locking at all: it is only accessed from within the thread.

Comment: But where did entries in queue come from? it comes from another thread constantly reading inputs, pushing to corresponding queue. Note that, there can not be multiple threads reading inputs simultaneously and processing inputs uncorrelated (because inputs are feed with random classes)